# firebase commands not working in vs code terminal 800a03ea error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, firebase, react-native, compiler-errors

[I am getting this error when running firebase init functions in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jT6S.png)

Here is my firebase.js code which I use to call firebase:

```
import * as firebase from '@firebase/app' //line 1 which seems to cause the error
//imports for webonly
const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default Firebase
```

I have also tried to import firebase from 'firebase' and 'react-native-firebase/app' but when trying to use cloud functions in firebase with firebase init functions I run into the error in the link

If anyone could help that would be very appreciated.
Thank you. Also, I am using react-native in expo if that matters

EDIT: All firebase commands are not working and giving the same error
This is the error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Dependencies:

`{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.14.3",
    "@firebase/messaging": "^0.6.13",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.3.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.1",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "^8.1.0",
    "fcm-node": "^1.5.2",
    "firebase": "^7.14.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-filesystem": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.2.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}`

SOLUTION: I am not sure if this qualifies for an answer but by making the default shell git BASH I was able to execute the commands

Answer (score 0):

You can import as follow:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: can you check the firebase is installed or not ? try to reinstall.

Comment: I reinstalled with npm from the rnFirebase site:https://rnfirebase.io/ but all firebase commands are giving the same error whether it is init or just --version